# Is $(-1)^{n!}$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I don't think I can use the alternating series test because of the factorial sign, but I don't know how else to solve this.  can you please give any hints ?

Comment: Hint: $n!$ is usually even.

Comment: Are you asking about the series (=the infinite sum) or the sequence? The lack of $\sum$-notation suggests that you are asking about the sequence, but then it baffles those of us not gifted with mind-reading abilities as to why you would bring up the alternating series test? Please clarify!

Answer (score 3):

For $n\geq 2$, note $n!$ is even so $(-1)^{n!}=1$. Thus this converges to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$(-1)^{n!} = 1$ for $n \ge 2$ (since $n! = n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times \dots \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$ is even for $n \ge 2$), so $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(-1)^{n!} = 1,$$and$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^{n!} = (-1) + (-1) + 1 + 1 + 1 + \dots$$does not converge.

Comment: Re-read the question

Comment: You are dealing with a series; the question is about a sequence.

Comment: The question asks wheter $\lim_n(-1)^{n!}$ exists, so please edit your answer.

Comment: In fairness to user243409 the OP does refer to the alternating **series** test. The question is unclear, and should either be clarified or taken behind the sauna.